# A discrete, linear graph at 45 degrees, where the N points add up to 1

Tags: graph-theory

I have a question:

I have a set of points that represent a graph (x0,x1..x9) Lets say 10 points. They are at a linear 45 degree angle up (Gradient 1). I am also told that (x0+x1+x2..x9 = 1).

How can I solve for each xi? Can I get an idea of how to start?

Comment: I tried writing it out as a series of equations, but it becomes an extremely complex 10 value equation to solve. There has to be an easier way

Comment: even worse, I am asked to model an equation or method of solving for an xn size, and a m gradient

Comment: There are very many ways for ten numbers to add up to 1. For example the numbers could be -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 1, 10, 20, 30, 40 ... or they could be 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.55. Do you have any information that would enable you to say one of these is not what you're looking for?

Comment: 10 scalar values don't make a graph, and a single equation in 10 unknowns is undeterminate. Please review your problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telling us that you have a linear graph seems to imply that $x$ is actually a function of an independent variable, and one should read $x(i)$ for $x_i$.

Then $x(i)$ must be a linear function with slope $1$, so that $x(i)=i+C$.

Using the given constraint,
$$(0+C)+(1+C)+\dots(9+C)=45+10C=1,$$
and $$C=-\frac{44}{10}.$$

Alternatively, if your data points are couples $(x_i,y_i)$ forming a straight line with unit slope, then all you can say is $$y=x+C,$$ and
$$\sum_{i=0}^9 y_i=1+10C,$$
but you can't guess $C$.

Comment: ah -44/10. that makes sense. not sure why i was getting confused by a simple problem